# memory leakage while using scanf for char* c

Tags: c, memory-leaks

can you please tell me what is wrong with the following input process?

the input should be a string length and then the string itself.

something like "5 vlady"

It works just fine, but valgrind (memory leakage tool) tell the following exception:

> Address 0x51ef184 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd

Her's the code:

```
unsigned int n;
char* string;

printf("Enter your string:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
string = (char*)calloc((n),sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", string);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The posted code is writing one byte beyond the allocated memory as `scanf("%s")` appends a terminating null character. Description for format specifier `s` from section *7.19.6.2 fscanf function* of the C99 standard:

> If no l length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence **and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically**.

Therefore allocate `n + 1` bytes.

Other:

- always check the result of IO operations to ensure variables have been assigned a value:

  ```
  /* 'scanf()' returns number of assignments made.
     Use '%u' for reading an unsigned int. */
  if (scanf("%u", &n) == 1)
  {
  }
  ```
- prevent buffer overrun by limiting the number of bytes consumed by `scanf()` by using the `%Ns` format specifier, where `N` is the number characters to read. In this case, the format specifier would need constructed, using [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for example. Another option is to use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) but this does not stop reading when white space is encountered.
- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)